# How to replace text string in a text file

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, text-files

I am new to vb.net and am trying to do something really simple.  I have this code which reads certain line of text from .ini file.

```
Dim FilePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\bin\userconfig.ini"
Dim text As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(FilePath)
Dim newText = text.Replace("UserName = ", TextBox_NewUser.Text)
IO.File.WriteAllText(FilePath, newText)
```

How do I make it replace that line of text after the `"="` with something you type in `TextBox_NewUser`. As you can see with current code it just replaces the whole `"UserName ="` which I don't want.

That specific line of text in the .ini by default has this value:

```
"UserName = Unnamed"
```

So how do I make it replace just that `"Unnamed"` with something I type in `TextBox_NewUser`?

Any assistance will be most appreciated.

Comment: I've used multiple lines to increase readability. I hope that's ok for you.

Comment: Are there multiple instances of this "UserName = Unnamed" case, or only one?

Comment: Better if you use a INI parser, see my **IniManager** class (and the commented examples inside): https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/tree/master/Solution/v1.2/Elektro.Application.Settings/Types

Comment: Luc Morin, there's just only one instance of "UserName"

Comment: Thank you ElektroStudios it is very useful, but I couldn't find an example for my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim newText = text.Replace("UserName = Unnamed", "UserName = " & TextBox_NewUser.Text)
```

Comment: Or:
`Dim newText = text.Replace("Unnamed",  TextBox_NewUser.Text)`

Comment: thank you for your reply, but you see that "Unnamed" is variable and could be anything. So if I'd try to change my name to something else yet again, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to go about this, there are additional assertions that could be done e.g. the code below assumes the lines don't begin with spaces and if they did you would first do a trim on each line before using StartsWith etc.

Config file

```
Role = Moderator
UserName = xxxx
Joined = 09/23/1006
```

Code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private fileName As String =
        IO.Path.Combine(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "userConfig.ini")
    ''' <summary>
    ''' assumes the file exist but does not assume there is text in
    ''' the text box.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="sender"></param>
    ''' <param name="e"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox_NewUser.Text) Then
            Dim lines As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName).ToList
            For index As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
                If lines(index).ToLower.StartsWith("username") Then
                    lines(index) = String.Concat("UserName = ", TextBox_NewUser.Text)
                End If
            Next
            IO.File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines.ToArray)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Sample project on Microsoft OneDrive, VS2013
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A3D5A9A9A28080D1!907&authkey=!AKQCanSTiCLP4mE&ithint=file%2czip

Comment: Will try this Karen, thank you. Code looks a bit complex for such a simple task.

Comment: Hi Darius47, in regards to complex code for a simple task, it's all dependent on a person's knowledge level, in this case of the vb.net language. Of course you could always go with the first answer which might be more to your liking as it's very simple. That is the beauty of this site, you can get varying ways to solve a question :-)